# What's the difference between (int) sizeof(void *) and int?

Tags: c, int, sizeof, void

I'm just a beginner for C programming.
Can I ask a simple question ?
What's the difference between  `(int) sizeof(void *)`  and  `int`  ?

ex)

```
#define ptrint          int
#define PTRINT          ((int) sizeof(void *))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first case acts as an alias for int so you can use ptrint instead of int.

The second case is the size of a pointer in bytes. So for instance on a 32 bit system it will return 4.

```
ptrint a = 8;
ptrint b = a;

int sizeofptr = PTRINT;
```

Answer (score 3):

One is a type, the other an expression returning the size of a type.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I ask one more question ? What is the size of (void *) ?

Comment: @user573566 The size of a pointer can differ depending on platform. On 32-bit platforms it's typically four bytes (32 bits), and on 64-bit platforms it's typically eight bytes (64 bits).

Answer (score 1):

With ptrint, you just define a new type that is just an alias for int, example:

```
ptrint a;
a = 5;
printf("%d",(int) a); // all this is ok.
```

with PTRINT, you define a integer constant that will contain the size of a void* pointer on your system. Example:

```
printf("Size of a void* pointer is %d\n",PTRINT); // will work. 
PTRINT a;  // will fail
```

Answer (score 0):

((int) sizeof(void *)) is a value (that depends of your system and compiler implementations), int is a type.